# What is the difference: SDL_FillRect VS SDL_RenderFillRect?

Tags: sdl-2

What is difference between these two functions:

[SDL_FillRect](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FillRect) VS [SDL_RenderFillRect](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderFillRect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SDL_FillRect()` operates on a `SDL_Surface` completely CPU-side, `SDL_RenderFillRect()` operates on a `SDL_Renderer` and may or may not be hardware accelerated depending on how the SDL_Renderer was created.

Comment: But why `SDL_FillRect` is documented as fast?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: Probably uses `memcpy()` or similar internally to fill each row, which can be faster than a manual for-loop that assigns each pixel.