# Why CPU-side version SDL_FillRect up to 7 times faster in compare GPU-side version SDL_RenderFillRect?

Tags: perl, sdl-2

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65442269/4632019) I have asked what is the difference between `SDL_FillRect` and `SDL_RenderFillRect`

[Here is code](https://github.com/KES777/sdl/blob/master/ffi.pl#L49) of my benchmark:

```perl
my $window  =  SDL2::Video::SDL_CreateWindow( 'Hello', 100, 100, 800, 600, 0x00000004 ); 
my $surface =  SDL2::Video::SDL_GetWindowSurface( $window );

my $render =  SDL2::Render::SDL_GetRenderer( $window );
SDL2::Render::SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( $render, 0, 0, 255, 255 );

use Benchmark ':all';

my $rect1 =  SDL2::Rect->new({ x => 10,  y => 10,  h => 50,  w => 50 });
 timethese( 1000000, {
     'Soft' => sub {
        SDL2::Surface::SDL_FillRect( $surface, $rect1, 0x00FF0000 );
     },
     'Hard' => sub {
        SDL2::Render::SDL_RenderFillRect( $render, $rect1 );
     },
 });
```

The result:

```
Benchmark: timing 1000000 iterations of Hard, Soft...
      Hard: 20 wallclock secs (13.06 usr +  8.03 sys = 21.09 CPU) @ 47415.84/s (n=1000000)
      Soft:  3 wallclock secs ( 2.91 usr +  0.01 sys =  2.92 CPU) @ 342465.75/s (n=1000000)
```

Why `CPU-side` version of function is much faster?
Probably I something wrong while benchmarking?

**UPD**

When rectangle is more bigger:

```
my $rect1 =  SDL2::Rect->new({ x => 10,  y => 10,  h => 550,  w => 750 });
```

```
Benchmark: timing 100000 iterations of Hard, Soft...
      Hard: 25 wallclock secs ( 1.51 usr +  2.50 sys =  4.01 CPU) @ 24937.66/s (n=100000)
      Soft: 25 wallclock secs (24.80 usr +  0.00 sys = 24.80 CPU) @ 4032.26/s (n=100000)

Benchmark: timing 1000000 iterations of Hard, Soft...
      Hard: 264 wallclock secs (16.67 usr + 23.98 sys = 40.65 CPU) @ 24600.25/s (n=1000000)
      Soft: 259 wallclock secs (258.00 usr +  0.34 sys = 258.34 CPU) @ 3870.87/s (n=1000000)
```

Comment: *"SDL2::Video::SDL_CreateWindow()"* : How did you install SDL2? I can only find [SDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/SDL) on metacpan.

Comment: I think I found SDL2 [here](https://github.com/PerlGameDev/SDL2). If I install that module, I get `Undefined subroutine &SDL2::Video::SDL_CreateWindow`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: No. Here I use my bindings to sdl2 via FFI: https://github.com/KES777/sdl/

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I have pushed test to github. Also SDL2 requires threaded perl. I use `perl-5.30.1t`

Comment: Hi Eugen, I tried to install it, but it fails. I added an [issue](https://github.com/KES777/sdl/issues/1)

Comment: Your linked question mentioned hardware acceleration, you haven't. Is that an option?
How do you know you are actually operating on the GPU?

Comment: @bytepusher: 1. `SDL_GetRenderDriverInfo` returns `opengl2` 2. Also notice that `Soft` version is x7 times faster. If I have no hardware acceleration then it should be same speed, but not slower, should not?

Comment: (Not an answer because I know close to nothing about the implementation of SDL) A quick look at the sources of SDL shows that [`SDL_FillRect`](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/master/src/video/SDL_fillrect.c) uses SSE extensions (when available, but I would expect your CPU to have them), whereas [`SDL_RenderFillRect`](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/master/src/render/SDL_render.c) does not.

Comment: (Still not an answer because I know close to nothing about GPUs as well) Furthermore, in your benchmark, your rectangle is quite small. There is probably an overhead to initialize whatever needs to be initialized for the GPU. The fact that the "sys" time is so high for the GPU-accelerated version (8.03 secs) compared to the CPU version (0.01 sec) might support this hypothesis. I don't really have time right now, but trying the same thing with a much larger rectangle could be interesting.

Comment: @Dada: I have added bench results for bigger rectangles